# How to prevent unnecessary renders in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Below is a minimal app that demonstrates my concern. If you run it you'll see that the build method of every visible item runs even when the data for only one item has changed.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> items;
  MyList(this.items);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          print("item $index built");
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('${items[index]}'),
          );
        });
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
   List<int> items = List<int>.generate(10000, (i) => i);

  void _incrementItem2() {
    setState(() {
      this.items[1]++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Long List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MyButton(_incrementItem2),
            Expanded(child: MyList(this.items))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function incrementItem2;
  void handlePress() {
    incrementItem2();
  }

  MyButton(this.incrementItem2);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
      ),
      onPressed: handlePress,
      child: Text('increment item 2'),
    );
  }
}
```

In React / React Native, I would use shouldComponentUpdate or UseMemo to prevent unnecessary renders. I'd like to do the same in Flutter.

Here is a link to a closed issue on the Flutter github on the same topic:
(I'll be commenting there with a link to this question)
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19421

**What are the best practices for avoiding useless "rerenders" or calls to the build method in Flutter, or are these extra builds not a serious concern given structural differences between Flutter and React?**

This is more or less similar this question asked on stack overflow a few years ago: [How to Prevent rerender of a widget based on custom logic in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084203/how-to-prevent-rerender-of-a-widget-based-on-custom-logic-in-flutter)

An upvoted answer given is to use ListView.builder. While that can prevent some if not most useless renders, it doesn't prevent all useless renders, as shown in my example.

Thanks in advance for your knowledge and insight.

Comment: use provider or bloc

Comment: check `ValueListenableBuilder` documentation (and see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-ZG-jS5QHQ&t=6s) but honestly i think that you exaggerate a bit with your performance concerns

Comment: Yes, not running into performance problems so far, but no exaggeration of concerns, @pskink, given a major reason I'm considering switching to flutter from React Native is performance.

Comment: ok how many times (per second for example) `MyList` rebuilds? also, how many visible items does it have in `ListView.builder`?

Comment: MyList's visible items (about 14 of them) would rebuild only once every time data was altered. In React Native, given the js bridge, this was was a concern. Glad to confirm this is less of a concern in Flutter.

Comment: it should not be any problem - as long as you dont have something really wrong in the code and `ListView.builder` rebuilds only those 14 visible items (plus 2 or maybe 3 additional ones) - i believe you checked that `print("item $index built");` does not print all the `items` ?

Comment: Even if the items are "heavy"? This is what Baker's answer suggests, "Keep in mind that while you may see rebuilds happening on your widgets which you can detect using print statements, you're not seeing Flutter optimizing renders which happens separately."

Comment: i dont know what you mean by "heavy" - but once built, they are reused when you scroll your list up/down - i mean their `RenderBox`es are reused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231885/discussion-between-benjamin-lee-and-pskink).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the key features of Flutter is that every Widget is its own unit and can decide to rebuild when needed.

The Bloc library gives really good control over what gets rebuilt. In the case of the text changing in your ListTile's you would have a MyListTile class:

```
class MyListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  MyListTile(this.index):super(key:ValueKey(index));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ItemBloc, ItemState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) {
        return previous.items[index] != current.items[index];
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return ListTile(title: Text('${state.items[index]}'));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

BlocBuilder's buildWhen is like the shouldComponentUpdate that you are used to in that it gives you a lot of control.

Comment: It may be useful to know that in addition to bloc, the 'select' in hooks_riverpod also works for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504553/is-there-an-equivalent-of-blocs-buildwhen-in-riverpod

Answer (score 5):

This is less of a proper answer, more where I'm sharing what I've been finding out while fielding answers.

As pointed out by @Baker, just because a build method is called unnecessarily doesn't necessarily mean that you're losing much performance.

I ran run repaint rainbow using the example, and like in React (https://felixgerschau.com/react-rerender-components/) just because a component/widget is rendered/built doesn't mean its repainted.

[image: Repaint rainbow, with or without provider. Only the updated item is repainted.]

Although, all code in the build method executes, and it does have to go through the diffing algorithm.

Using BLOC I was able to prevent unneeded renders (setState on left, BLOC on right):

[image]

Here's the simple example in the question with BLOC implementation:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocProvider<ListBloc>(
        create: (context) => ListBloc(),
        child: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      print("item $index built");
      return MyListTile(index);
    });
  }
}

class MyListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  MyListTile(this.index) : super(key: ValueKey(index));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ListBloc, List<int>>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) {
        return previous[index] != current[index];
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return ListTile(title: Text('${state[index]}'));
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Long List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[MyButton(), Expanded(child: MyList())],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  MyButton();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void handlePress() {
      BlocProvider.of<ListBloc>(context).add(ListEvent.incrementItem2);
    }

    return TextButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
      ),
      onPressed: handlePress,
      child: Text('increment item 2'),
    );
  }
}

//BLOC
enum ListEvent { incrementItem2 }

class ListBloc extends Bloc<ListEvent, List<int>> {
  ListBloc() : super(List<int>.generate(10000, (i) => i));

  @override
  Stream<List<int>> mapEventToState(ListEvent event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case ListEvent.incrementItem2:
        List<int> newState = [...state];
        newState[1]++;
        yield newState;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Wasn't able to use Provider to prevent each item from rebuilding, as `notifyListeners()` will trigger a rebuild to all consumers and their children. Here's my attempt:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ItemsNotifier(), child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var items = Provider.of<ItemsNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    final title = 'Long List';

    void _incrementItem2() {
      items.incrementItem(2);
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MyButton(_incrementItem2),
            Expanded(child: MyList(items))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  final ItemsNotifier items;
  MyList(this.items);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          print("item $index built");
          return MyListItem(items[index],
              key: ValueKey(items[index].id)
          );
        });
  }
}

class MyListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyItem item;
  MyListItem(this.item, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('item ${item.value} built');
    return Consumer<ItemsNotifier>(builder: (context, model, child) {
      return ListTile(title: Text('Item ${item.value}'));
    });
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function incrementItem2;
  void handlePress() {
    incrementItem2();
  }

  MyButton(this.incrementItem2);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
      ),
      onPressed: handlePress,
      child: Text('increment item 2'),
    );
  }
}

class MyItem {
  int id;
  int value;
  MyItem({@required this.id, @required this.value});
  void incrementValue() {
    this.value = value + 1;
  }
}

class ItemsNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<MyItem> _myItems =
      List<MyItem>.generate(1000, (i) => MyItem(id: i, value: i));

  List<MyItem> get all {
    return (List.unmodifiable(_myItems));
  }

  int get length => _myItems.length;

  MyItem operator [](int i) => _myItems[i];

  void incrementItem(int itemId) {
    MyItem item = _myItems.firstWhere((item) => item.id == itemId);
    item.incrementValue();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue, optimize when you see performance issues / jankiness, but it's prob. not worthwhile to do so prior to do that.  Flutter team did a [short video about this](https://youtu.be/PKGguGUwSYE?t=18).

Keep in mind that while you may see rebuilds happening on your widgets which you can detect using `print` statements, you're not seeing Flutter optimizing renders which happens separately.

Flutter has a widget tree, an element tree and a renderObject tree.

[Image taken from Architectural Overview](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/architectural-overview#build-from-widget-to-element).

[image: Flutter build flow]

The widget tree is our hand-coded Dart blueprint for what we want built. (Only blue items on left tree. White items are underlying: we don't write that directly.)

The element tree is Flutter's interpretation of our blueprint, with more detail on what actual components are used and what will be needed for layout and rendering.

The renderObject tree will produce a list of items with details on their dimensions, layer-depth, etc. that needs rasterization onto screen.

The blueprint may be erased and rewritten many times, but that doesn't mean all (or even many) of the underlying components are destroyed/re-created/re-rendered/re-positioned.  Components that haven't changed will be re-used.

Say we're building a bathroom that contains a sink and bathtub.  Owner decides he wants to swap locations of the sink and bathtub.  The contractor doesn't take a sledgehammer and pulverize the ceramics and buys/transports and installs a brand new sink and tub.  He just detaches each and swaps their location.

Here's a contrived example using `AnimatedSwitcher`:

```
        child: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            child: Container(
                key: key,
                color: color,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Text('Billy'))),
```

`AnimatedSwitcher` is supposed to cross-fade its children when they change. (Say from blue to green in this case.)  But if `key` isn't provided, `AnimatedSwitcher` won't be rebuilt and won't do a cross-fade animation.

When Flutter walks the element tree and arrives at `AnimatedSwitcher`, it checks to see if its child has obviously changed, i.e. different tree structure, different element Type etc., but it won't do a deep inspection (too costly I assume).  It sees the same object Type (`Container`) in the same tree position (immediate child) and keeps `AnimatedSwitcher` without rebuilding it.  The result is the `Container` (when it is rebuilt since its color has changed) flips from green to blue with no animation.

Adding a unique `key` to `Container` helps Flutter identify them as different when analyzing the `AnimatedSwitcher` sub-tree for optimization.  Now Flutter will rebuild `AnimatedSwitcher` about 30 times during its 500ms duration to visually show the animation. (Flutter aims for 60fps on most devices.)

Here's the above `AnimatedSwitcher` used in a copy/paste example:

- on first load, the box flips from green to blue without animation (key didn't change)
- press the refresh button in AppBar to reset the page, but the key is updated for the blue `Container`, allowing Flutter to spot the difference and do its rebuilds for `AnimatedSwitcher`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedSwitcherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedSwitcherPageState createState() => _AnimatedSwitcherPageState();
}

class _AnimatedSwitcherPageState extends State<AnimatedSwitcherPage> {
  Color color = Colors.lightGreenAccent;
  ValueKey key;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    key = ValueKey(color.value);

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () => _update(useKey: false));
    // this initial color change happens WITHOUT key changing
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Animation Switcher'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.refresh), onPressed: _restartWithKey)
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            child: Container(
                key: key,
                color: color,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Text('Billy'))),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _update({bool useKey}) {
    setState(() {
      color = Colors.lightBlueAccent;
      if (useKey) key = ValueKey(color.value);
    });
  }

  void _restartWithKey() {
    setState(() {
      color = Colors.lightGreenAccent; // reset color to green
    });
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () => _update(useKey: true));
    // this refresh button color change happens WITH a key change
  }
}
```

#### Addendum for Comments

**Question**: 
I understand that it won't do the animation unless the keys are different, but if it's not rebuilding, then why/how is the color switching from green to blue?

**Reply**: 
`AnimatedSwitcher` is a `StatefulWidget`.  It saves the previous child widget between builds.  When a new build occurs, it compares old child vs. new child. (See `Widget.canUpdate()` method for the comparison.)

If the old and new child are distinct/different, it performs a transition animation, for X amount of frames/ticks.

If the old child and new child are *not* distinct/different (as per `.canUpdate()`), `AnimatedSwitcher` is basically an unneeded wrapper: it won't do anything special, but does do a rebuild to maintain its latest child (?). I have to admit this was poor choice of example.

Comment: I understand that it won't do the animation unless the keys are different, but if it's not rebuilding, then why/how is the color switching from green to blue?

Comment: Is there a debugging / profiling method that enables you to know how often elements are rendering?

Comment: @BenjaminLee In Android Studio you can click on Flutter Performance/Widget Rebuild stats and see how often which Widgets get rebuild.

Comment: @BenjaminLee I replied to your question as an Addendum for Comments above.

Comment: @Baker, so the call to setState caused the container to both build and rerender... I thought this example was supposed to illuminate how Flutter avoids extra renders? What is this example intending to show? (and does it answer the question?) Just because Flutter can walk the element tree and, seeing a new key, trigger an animation, doesn't mean that it out-of-the box avoids extra renders without using something like provider.

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's a pretty crap example now that I look at the details of how `AnimatedSwitcher` works.  I think it still does a regular rebuild, just not the expensive animation transition.

Comment: I'm guessing the rebuild is done to keep track of the latest child so it can compare it to new children on future rebuilds & know when to perform the animation.