# Is there an equivalent of bloc's buildwhen in riverpod?

Tags: flutter, bloc, riverpod

Bloc's `buildwhen` allows you to only rebuild list items that have updated. (See the article here: [How to prevent unnecessary renders in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67358514/how-to-prevent-unnecessary-renders-in-flutter))

Is there an equivalent feature or way of preventing these type of unneeded builds in riverpod?

Comment: There are two ways, using `ScopedProvider` or the select method from `hooks_riverpod` each have deferent use case but they are what we use to filter rebuilds in riverpod.

Comment: `select` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `select` method, available when using HooksWidget / hooks_riverpod works nicely. The widget only rebuilds when the callback given to select changes.

[This documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/RootProvider/select.html) for it is up to date as of this posting.